# Windows VAD Tree and GDT LDT relationship X86

Tags: winapi, windows-kernel

i was searching how Windows memory works with X86
I learnt something but i am in dilemma is it true or not.
I did not found any docs on the internet relationship between VAD and GDT

Windows OS uses VAD ( Virtual Address Descriptors ) to allocate address from LDT or GDT array.

As i read , each VAD entry is just a "page table"

so :

For processes each page table is LDT entry
For Kernel each page table is GDT entry

NTOSKRNL.EXE when OS boots inits VADs 
by calling RtlInitializeGenericTable
This function makes a binary tree , each node contains free LDT or GDT entry.
this binary tree root is stored inside GDT itself.

When we allocate a memory from user mode malloc , binary tree subtract one LDT node from LDT pool and VAD tree root.

My second question:
Windows can run number of processes is the limit of GDT entries
x86 can have 16bit GDT entries so we can add 65536 LDT entries
each process can have 1 LDT entry.
So GDT can contains up to 60K entries.
That means Windows can run max ~60k process
is this true ?

---

Comment: full drivel. from begin to end. VAD absolute not related to GDT and LDT(in practic not used in Windows).

Comment: VADs are used to keep track of what memory pages a process allocated/reserved etc. VADs are stored in an AVL tree the root of which is stored in the EPROCESS structure of the owning process in the `VadRoot` field. If you wish to see the VADs, you my use my old tool https://jadro-windows.cz/projekty/vad/ (the texts are in Czech, the tool should be in English). It hopefully works up to Windows 7 even in these days.

Comment: so whats inside GDT and LDT on Windows ?